# /proc/mounts does not have Source info like /proc/self/mountinfo has

Tags: linux, go, kubernetes, filesystems

I am working on a go application where I want to use the the mount-utils package: https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/utils/mount

Here, this package parses /proc/mounts file instead of /proc/self/mountinfo.

How do I figure out value for source using this package? This piece of information is missing in /proc/mounts file as compared to /proc/self/mountinfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mount.ParseMountInfo](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/utils/mount#ParseMountInfo) parses `/proc/<pid>/mountinfo`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "k8s.io/utils/mount"
)

func main() {
    mounts, err := mount.ParseMountInfo("/proc/self/mountinfo")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, m := range mounts {
        fmt.Printf("%-100s%s\n", m.MountPoint, m.Source)
    }
}
```

BTW, The package `k8s.io/utils/mount` has been moved to new location. Use `k8s.io/mount-utils` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I was insure if I can give "self" in place of PID.

Comment: At first, I tested with a PID (returned from `os.Getpid()`). And then replaced the PID with `self`. Both worked.